# Failed to require PlatformApi instance for platform "android". Using polyfill instead

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have recently upgraded my Ionic/Cordova dev environment and am having issues rebuilding my project. Initially when building the project, I was getting an error as the `cordova-plugin-device` plugin was used installed twice and thus couldnt be accessed by the phone.

I went to remove my android platform and re-add it so it would have to reinstall the plugins taking into account the dependencies for each plugin.

[image]

When I tried to add my platform back again, I received the `Failed to require PlatformApi instance for platform "android". Using polyfill instead.` error which then cast an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` error.

My development environment is as follows:

```
Cordova CLI: 5.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Node Version: v5.3.0
```

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this error?  I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: No I haven't yet sorry. I managed to solve my issue without needing to uninstall the platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This worked for me after experiencing the same problem**

I have found that making sure that I had to make sure that I have that the `id` attribute had to be filled in the `<widget>` tag in the `config.xml` file. i.e. it should look something like this `<widget id="com.example.app" ...>`.

In my case I had removed the `id` attribute because I was using `android-packageName` and `ios-CFBundleIdentifier` so I could have different package names (bundle identifier) for Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks @Kholofelo. This is exactly my issue as I also have package names for my app in each store! What a simple solution!

Comment: I'm amused that we answered a 9 day old question within 14 minutes of each other ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I was missing the ID attribute in the widget element of config.xml.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-platform-add-give-an-error/41626

Running

cordova -d platform add android

Let me see the stack trace and find the line in cordova that was causing the error.  This led me to where the issue was in my configuration.